# Access - change DB icon

Tags: ms-access, vba

Is there any way to change a desktop icon for only one Access DB ? And not using shorcut for icons ?...I've found some examples for doing this, but nothing seems to work for me.

Any help much appreciated !

Comment: You need a shortcut for this.

Comment: Shortcut would be o.k., If icon wouldn't be seen as shortcut.

Answer (score 2):

not sure if this is what you're looking for but in Office 2010 for example Go to 
Access Options & Click Current Database. Under Application Options, in the Application Icon box, you can either type in the full Path of the icon that you want or browse to the file location. 
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Add-a-custom-title-or-icon-to-a-database-0e43e135-dd0d-4451-84ea-4f547e14480e

Comment: No, that is not what I posted.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know why answer was deleted, but once again - you can't change Access DB icon for only 1 file, except using shortcuts method - which is not same.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure that you can do this using the package and distribute wizard. You can then distribute the database as an executable file, I think (not 100%). this would show without the shortcut arrow on the desktop.

> File> save and publish> package solution

You may first have to go to *options> add-ins > manage com add-ins* and enable the package solution add-in.

Comment: I tried, but strangely i dont' find Acces file anywhere on PC (win 7) when I install It via wizzard, although It's shown in installed programs. Dont know if this has to do something with our company IT policy.

Comment: Its a long time since I used it. I thought the package solution created an 'installer' which you can launch. does the wizard not ask you where you want to save the files?

Comment: Wizzard let's you choose where to install package solution. Then you install package solution's "Setup.Exe", but It installs god knows where, done all searching I could in Win 7, but nowhere to be seen, except under Control panel/Programs - from which I cant launch It or see any path of program.